# Отправка сообщения из текстового поля на сайте в аську

Tags: icq, php

Скажите, а возможно ли как-то организовать отправку сообщения из текстового поля на сайте в аську определенному человеку. То есть посетитель заходит на сайт, пишет что-то в поле сообщений, нажимаеет ввод и вуаля, сообщение отправляется мне в аську.

Comment: Да, точно возможно. Но я использовал PHP-ICQ, а это накладывает некоторые ограничения.  
BUMP!, сам хочу посмотреть на нормальное решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть один [класс для работы с ICQ](http://wip.asminog.com/workshop/php2icq.html). Если честно, я его не пробовал, но по примеру очень похоже на то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Я про него и говорил. У него есть крайне непрятный недостаток: для использования как хочет автор, его придется разорить и перелопатить весьма конкретно: он соединается КАЖДЫЙ раз при запуске, вместо того чтобы проверять есть ли соединение. Мне в свое время оказалось это делать лениво.

Comment: Использую эту штуку, нареканий пока не было. Единственное, вам бы посоветовал оформить как демона и слать запросы на него

    user
      ->action.php
      ->localhost:%DAEMON_PORT%  -->  admin_icq
            |
    user  <-'

Вот примерная схема

Comment: @knes, неужели и правда, там придется лопатить дофига кода? Как я понимаю, реально нужны две функции: login и close.

Comment: Правда. Скажем так: прошлогодняя версия именно так и выглядела - там были слишком тесно переплетены функции логина и работы с сообщениями, настолько, что оказалось проще написать что-то типа лайвоператора.

Comment: та ну вы че, там максимум, не трогая класс, страницу кода на демона и полстраницы на обработчик формы %) `while($icq->isConnected()) { ловим_запрос_на_порту_3128(); шлем_на_номер_админа(); спим(2); }`

Comment: спасибо, нашел